# Python in TextMate - run script in IDLE?

Tags: python, textmate

Is it possible for TextMate to run Python scripts in IDLE instead of internally or via Terminal?

Rather than just use the Python build that comes with IDLE installation I want the shell window to actually launch so I can type in the interactive session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a play on OSX, and I think I've got it working.

Open TextMate's Bundle Editor (`Bundles` -> `Bundle Editor` -> `Show Bundle Editor`)

On the left hand side: Expand `Python`, then duplicate your "Run Script" command (bottom corner, second-left button [++]), and name it "Run Script in IDLE"

Choose a keyboard shortcut, and put it in the box next to **Activation**: Key Equivalent

Replace the following line:

```
TextMate::Executor.run(ENV["TM_PYTHON"] || "python", "-u", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"]) do |str, type|
```

with

```
TextMate::Executor.run("/usr/bin/idle2.7", "-r", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"]) do |str, type|
```

This supplies your filepath as an argument to idle, as if you ran `/usr/bin/idle2.7 -r /path/to/script.py` directly. (Or whatever python version you're using - /usr/bin/idle3.1 etc)

You could also use the `-e` flag instead of the `-r` flag, to edit your script in IDLE instead of running it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Alex that post is cool, I tried setting TM_PYTHON to /usr/local/bin/python3 which updates the Python build TM uses, but I was hoping for IDLE to actually launch, as the Terminal does with "run in Terminal". Are you using TM on Windows?

Comment: I can't get this to work on Textmate2.. Would you mind taking another look how it would work there?

Comment: @altabq I'm afraid I haven't used Textmate for a long time - I wrote this answer 5 years ago! I'm using Sublime Text 3 now, check out https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL